# Can the classic Account Administrator on an Azure Subscription be changed, when the original Account Owner no longer exsists?

Tags: azure, azure-subscription

We have several (MSDN/Visual Studio Enterprise) Azure Subscriptions that was created by users that no longer exists in our Active Directory.

As a Global Administrator I'm able to do *almost* everything, including giving owner rights. But I found a few things that only the classic Account Administrator can do:

- Re-activate a deactivated subscription
- Update Subscription Address
- Change the Service Administrator

Is there a way to change the Account owner/Account Administrator (both names are use in Azure) of a subscription, if that user does not exist anymore?

Bonus: Is this also possible if the subscription is diabled?

Here I'm trying to reactivate a disabled MSDN/Visual Studio Enterprise subscription, but I can't because I'm not the Account Administrator:
[image: Reactivate subscription]

Here I'm trying to change the Service Administrator on an active subscription. I have owner rights, but I'm not the Account Administrator:
[image: Change service admin]

Here I'm trying to delete resources on a disabled subscription. But I cannot because I cannot reactive the subscription. This in turn means I cannot even delete resources and free up global unique names:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK,

> Reactivating the Disabled MSDN/VS Enterprise Subscription without Account Administrator Role access. Only the Account Administrator can switch offer on this subscription.

You should have appropriate administrator role access on the Subscription scope to manage the Subscriptions and follow the steps provided in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/switch-azure-offer) for switching to different models of Azure Subscriptions.

> Changing the Service Administrator with Owner Right but no-Account Admin role assigned.

I believe being the Service Administrator can change the Service Administrator details if the user is assigned with the Subscription Scope Owner role as stated in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/classic-administrators#change-the-service-administrator) of Changing the Service Admin in Azure.

[image]

> I'm trying to delete resources on a disabled subscription. But I cannot because I cannot reactive the subscription. This in turn means I cannot even delete resources and free up global unique names.

You cannot delete the resources on disabled subscription because it allows Read-only access on the resources within the disabled subscription.

If there are any issues in deleting the resources, mail the details to ***Microsoft Support*** - ***supportmail@microsoft.com*** so that they would assist the possible steps, or they will delete that disabled subscription from the backend by confirming your consent.

Comment: Thanks. As my screenshot shows... I cannot click "Change service admin" (like you show) as I'm not the Account Administrator. I will try to ask Microsoft Support. Since August this problem have occurred 4 times, and I have 4 disabled subscriptions. So I was hoping for a PowerShell command or the like.

Comment: In the disabled subscriptions, all the resources become read-only access even we are the owner of subscription. In this case, we need to contact Microsoft Support where they will do suggest or required operations on backend based on our requirements.

Comment: I was actually able to delete the majority of the resources after it got disabled... but not the virtual network, and I an also not purge a Key Vault.

Comment: After the subscription got disabled, only Read-only access will be activated on the resources so difficult to delete. We need to raise the support request for deleting the resources on backend by MS Subscription Support Team